# $resource service: Arguments for "class" and "instance" methods

Tags: angularjs

In [oficial docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource) nothing write about callback function.

I have service:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .factory('Thing', ['$resource',
    function ($resource) {
      return $resource('/api/things/:id', { id: 'all' }, {} );
    }
  );
```

And i have controller:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('ThingCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$routeParams', 'Thing',
    function ($scope, $location, $routeParams, Thing) {

      Thing.get({id: $routeParams.thingId}, function(thing) {
        // This callback i found in example
        $scope.thing = thing;
      });

      $scope.save = function() {
        Thing.save({id: $scope.thing._id}, $scope.thing, function() {
          // This callback i found using brute force. It run when respond OK (200)
        });
      };
    }
  ]);
```

I want understand how use this callbacks.
I want know what takes this callbacks.

Can anybody helps me?

p.s. sorry if my english is not well...

Comment: The callback is the response from the server, so whatever you have setup.

Comment: When .get callback is second parameter and takes respond, maybe something else?

Comment: When .save callback is third parameter and takes... i dont know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging into the source code (version 1.2.16), it turns out that each *instance* method can receive up to 3 arguments:

1. [optional] Parameters, e.g. (`{id: 'some-ID'}`).
2. [optional] A success callback.
3. [optional] An error callback.

The success/error callbacks are called as soon as the resonse arrives.

---

The callbacks receive the following arguments:

- **success callback**:
  a. The object (e.g. a `thing`).
  b. A header getter function.
- **error callback**:
  a. The object (e.g. a `thing`).

---

If you read the docs really carefully, you will be able to spot it somewhere there:

> It's worth noting that the success callback for get, query and other methods gets passed in the response that came from the server as well as $http header getter function [...]:

```
var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
User.get({userId:123}, function (user, getResponseHeaders) {
    user.abc = true;
    user.$save(function (usr, putResponseHeaders) {
        //usr => saved user object
        //putResponseHeaders => $http header getter
    });
});
```

---

**UPDATE**

There is an important (and not so obvious) difference between a resource *class* and resource *instances*.

A resource *class* object is returned by calling the `$resource` service.
A resource *instance* object is returned by calling methods of a resource *class* object.

To clarify, in this example:

```
var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
var user = User.get({userId:123});
```

- `User` is a resource *class* object (since it is returned by calling `$resource(...)`).
- `user` is a resource *instance* object (since it is returned by calling the `.get()` method of a resource *class* object, i.e. `User`).

Now, a resource *class* object *has "static" method for each action in the definition*.
The rsource *instance* object _ is an instance of the resource type and all of the non-GET methods are available with $ prefix_.

In other words, `User` (*class*) has **static** methods `get()`, `save()`, `delete()` etc.
whereas `user` (*instance*) has prefixed, non-GET methods, e.g. `$save()`, `$delete()` etc. (but not `$get()` or `$query()).

The non-static methods receive the arguments I described earlier.
The static GET methods receive also the same arguments (as described earlier)
The static non-GET methods receive an extra argument, the data to be posted, i.e. the *instance* object to be acted upon.

So, those two calls are identical:

```
user.$save(params, success, error);        // <-- non-static method
User.save(params, user, success, error);   // <-- static method
```

---

**UPDATE 2**:

Only after it is too late, I discovered the method arguments are quite clearly described in the docs:

> The action methods on the class object or instance object can be invoked with the following parameters:

- HTTP GET "class" actions: `Resource.action([parameters], [success], [error])`
- non-GET "class" actions:  `Resource.action([parameters], postData, [success], [error])`
- non-GET instance actions: `instance.$action([parameters], [success], [error])`

> Success callback is called with (`value`, `responseHeaders`) arguments.
>   Error callback is called with (`httpResponse`) argument.
>
> Class actions return empty instance (with additional properties below).
>   Instance actions return promise of the action.

Comment: Thank you. But i dont understand why my code work?: Thing.save({id: $scope.thing._id}, $scope.thing, function() {/*success callback*/}); Success callback on third place. On second plase is object which i want to save (send to 'server').

Comment: I updated my answer (twice) with a more detailed explanation. It turns out it is all documented (so there was no need to dig into the source code in the first place) :)

Comment: The biggest problem with angular documentation is that it is not consistent. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @arty: What do you mean ? Do you have a specific example in mind ?